# vb.net evaluate simple math expressions natively

Tags: vb.net

like `evaluate()` in VBA, is there any native way of evaluating a simple math expression in vb.net ?

ex :

```
Dim exp as String
exp = "2+3"
MsgBox(exp)
```

expecting 5 in message box.

Comment: Programming questions are strictly out of scope here at Super User

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate mathematical expression from a string using VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178637/evaluate-mathematical-expression-from-a-string-using-vb)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating string “3*(4+2)” yield int 18](https://stackoverflow.com/q/333737/11683)

Comment: thanks, but those are not native answers, correct me if im wrong, i guess there's no way other than importing custom libraries.

Comment: Yeah, you can do this in strict native code, basically iterate through each character in the string then making a decision to on what o do with it.  Maybe will need to working in something like regex to pull the string into numeric and operator components, then you've got the order of operations to consider.  Much simpler to reach out to external libraries where all the heavy lifting has already been done

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65798782/math-expression-parsing-incorrect-output-when-a-followed-by-a/65802154#65802154

Comment: thanks, everyone for the suggestions, so the conclusion is either import 3rd party libraries or write your own either from scratch or adopting what's available. so the simple answer is there's no inbuilt function as its available in VBA.